# Using CORS to access HTTP Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, http, cookies, cors

I have a user who's on Domain A. When they make a request to Domain A, I want Domain A to reach out to Domain B. Once the request hits Domain B, I want Domain B to access HTTP Cookies that the user has *on Domain B* and not on Domain A. Is this possible to do with CORS?

So to rehash.

1. User visits `www.example.com`
2. A cross-domain request is made from `www.example.com` -> `www.example.net`
3. `www.example.net` inspects HTTP Cookies ON `www.example.net` and NOT `www.example.com` for the requesting user.

Obviously out of the box this does not work. I am looking for a secure solution that does work.

The idea here is I own both `www.example.com` and `www.example.net` and I want to log to a `www.example.net` database when a user visits `www.example.com` IF they have a specific HTTP Cookie set on `www.example.net`.

**UPDATE**

I have setup CORS on a test server-side script (`www.example.net` for the purpose of this example):

```
<?PHP       
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 60');    
    
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
        
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    
        exit(0);
    }
    
    echo "Cookie Dump: \n";
    echo print_r($_COOKIE);
```

And on `www.example.com`, the client, I am simply using the `fetch` API:

```
<script>
  fetch("https://badge-dev.myfreecams.com/codex/auth.php", {
     method: 'GET',
     credentials: 'include'
   }).then(data => console.log(data));
</script>
```

There are not any CORS errors. If I visit the server-side script directly in my browser, I see a proper dump of client-side HTTP Cookies. However, when `www.example.com` is loaded, they are not dumped. That means I cannot do what I need to do on my server, `www.example.net` since the `$_COOKIE` array is empty.

Comment: Did you try with iframe?

Comment: In `example.com` a dynamic iframe with src to `example.net` generated and appended to body then you can access to `example.net` cookies

Comment: @Lessmore I'd need more information to be able to test this.

Comment: to try read about Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * https://dev.to/lydiahallie/cs-visualized-cors-5b8h we made this configuration on our server nginx (or apache)

Comment: Did you try my solution (iframe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `example.com` we have a page with an iframe that load a page from `example.net`.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<iframe src="http://example.net/log.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And in `example.net` we have a `.php` file for read and write cookie (or anything you want to do by cookies):

```
<?php
$visits = isset($_COOKIE['visits']) ? intval($_COOKIE['visits']) : 0;
var_dump($_COOKIE);
$visits += 1;
setcookie('visits', $visits, time() + 3600);
```

**Some notes:**

In my dev environment (Win10, Chrome 87) Chrome avoid cross-site cookies. Chrome 80+ added a new attribute in set-cookie, called `SameSite` for improving privacy. [For more info read this - SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)

In your case this option need to be `None` like this `SameSite=None` and your domains must be `https`

in nutshell, your set cookie command should have `... Secure; SameSite=None` for example:

```
header("Set-Cookie: key=value; path=/; domain=example.net; Secure; SameSite=None");
```

In my development environment i haven't https domains, so i disable chrome SameSite for my tests [Turning off Google Chrome SameSite Cookie Enforcement](https://support.siteimprove.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360007364778-Turning-off-Google-Chrome-SameSite-Cookie-Enforcement)

Answer (score 0):

If you set [the `credentials` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) on a cross-origin request, then cookies for the URL the request is being made to will be included. However, this will trigger a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) before the request including the credentials will be set.

```
fetch("//example.net/", {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
});
```

Comment: I thought this would work also, but when I dump Cookies on the server, it doesn't show any. If I visit the server-side script directly, the Cookies are there. No CORS errors.